# Using Google BigQuery's Comma as UNION ALL with IN clause

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am attempting to perform the following query:

```
SELECT 
  author, link_id, COUNT(link_id) as cnt
FROM 
  [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2015_12],
  [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2015_11]
WHERE link_id IN (
  SELECT posts.name
  FROM [fh-bigquery:reddit_posts.full_corpus_201512] AS posts
  WHERE posts.subreddit = 'politics'
  ORDER BY posts.created_utc DESC
  LIMIT 300
)
GROUP BY author, link_id
ORDER BY author
```

I receive this error message upon execution: *JOIN (including semi-join) and UNION ALL (comma, date range) may not be combined in a single SELECT statement. Either move the UNION ALL to an inner query or the JOIN to an outer query.*

Removing one of the `comments` tables works fine however I can't seem to figure out how BigQuery's [Comma as UNION ALL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#comma_as_union_all) works. I've attempted to move the union to an inner query but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error was in my misunderstanding of *move the UNION ALL to an inner query*. The resolve the error, I had to put the two tables in a basic `select * from ...`. The working query is as follows:

```
SELECT 
  author, link_id, COUNT(link_id) as cnt
FROM (
  SELECT * 
  FROM
    [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2015_12],
    [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2015_11]
  )
WHERE link_id IN (
  SELECT posts.name
  FROM [fh-bigquery:reddit_posts.full_corpus_201512] AS posts
  WHERE posts.subreddit = 'politics'
  ORDER BY posts.created_utc DESC
  LIMIT 300
)
GROUP BY author, link_id
ORDER BY author
```